# KineticJS: How do you position shapes in a group relative to a new origin?

Tags: kineticjs

I would like to be able to position shapes in a group relative to a new origin, and I would like to set that new origin to be the coordinates of the group's. Essentially creating something like a mini-canvas, where the group is the canvas.

For example, say I have a group `card`, and in it I have `Kinetic.Text` objects. Instead of having to do something like `Kinetic.Text({x: group_x + text_x, y: group_y + text_y})` to calculate the coordinates of the text which will be sitting on top of the card, it might be neat if `text_x` and `text_y` in `Kinetic.Text({x: text_x, y: text_y})` were calculated based on the group it's in.

It's like, the group is kind of a mini-canvas in itself, with a bunch of shapes in it. Does KineticJS support this natively? Or is there no other option than to formulate the positioning of shapes sitting on top of shapes?

I'm probably going to want to keep a shape centered on top of another shape, I imagine I would need a simple formula, but I would rather use a feature KineticJS might provide. Does KineticJS provide any features for this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried .getPosition() which gets the object's position relative to its parent--and for grouped objects the parent should be the group container:

```
myTextInGroup.getPosition().x
myTextInGroup.getPosition().y
```

and then set the position of the child object like this:

```
myTextInGroup.setPosition(newX,newY);
```

Comment: Actually it would be `myTextInGroup.setPosition(newX,newY);`
Also in latest versions of KineticJS it would be `myTextInGroup.setPosition({x:newX, y:newY});`